# Animation onAnimationEnd not called when Fragment onPause

Tags: android, animation, fragment

```
val rotate = RotateAnimation(
    degreeOld, degree,
    RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f).also {
    it.duration = animationDuration
    it.fillAfter = true
    it.repeatCount = repeatCount
    it.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
            onAnimationEnd()// do something
        }
    })
}
viewBinding.img.startAnimation(rotate)
```

There is a view in Fragment and i set animation on it.

Everything works. But when Fragment onPause, `onAnimationEnd` is not called.

```
override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
    onAnimationEnd()//  not called when Fragment onPause
}
```

It cant be solved in fragment `onHiddenChanged` or `onResume` etc. because I have to do something after animation end.

How to solve it.